# displaying error on datagridview's combobox column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I'm trying make a new user managing panel for my winform project. Basically i want to display a combobox which lets administrative user to determine role for other users in **Role** column of gridview. Combobox content has just 3 items such as "***Admin***" , "***User***" , "***Client***" but gives me a set of error over **DataError event**.

All i did was right clicking on the gridview. Then click on "**Edit Columns**" , on the opening panel, i choose "Role" column and changed its ColumnType property to **DataGridViewComboBoxColumn** . Then i added name of roles into **Items** property's collection as one per line.

[image]

Below you can see my code, winform design and error messages. How can i make it work without giving error messages?

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace XXX
{
    public partial class UserManager : Form
    {
        public UserManager()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UserManager_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 88, 55, 55);

            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'xXXDataSet.users' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.usersTableAdapter.Fill(this.xXXDataSet.users);

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs anError)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error happened " + anError.Context.ToString());

            if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Commit error");
            }
            if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cell change");
            }
            if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Parsing)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("parsing error");
            }
            if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.LeaveControl)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("leave control error");
            }

            if ((anError.Exception) is ConstraintException)
            {
                DataGridView view = (DataGridView)sender;
                view.Rows[anError.RowIndex].ErrorText = "an error";
                view.Rows[anError.RowIndex].Cells[anError.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = "an error";

                anError.ThrowException = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `DataGridView` data-bound? If yes, show its `DataSource`. You must be sure the underlying data of the cells at column `role` should be contained/present in the `Items` of the combobox at column `role`. For example, if your combobox's Items contains only `a,b,c` but the underlying cell can have some different value like `d` -> the format exception will throw.

Comment: *DataSource* property of my gridview is *userBindingSource*
,
So basically you're saying, role column of my database table's data type is nvarchar(50). and it can have something different then my combobox's items. And this gives me an error?

Comment: Yes, the example I gave in the previous comment demonstrates that clearly. You have to collect all the possible values to build the `Items` for your combobox.

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't understand how its suppose to be collected from database. I just want to display a, b and c in combobox then record one of them with other data of users. Should i make another database table that holds just user role types?

Comment: your `role` column are supposed to hold **only supported/designed roles** in your table, of course when you design your database table, there should have some table like `Role`, you should pull data from this table to fill your `comboboxes`. All the possible values (role types) should be contained in the collection you got. **Otherwise, your database design is wrong**.